# Referenced file contains errors (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app.xsd)

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd

I faced this error in Eclipse:

> Referenced file contains errors (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app.xsd). For more information, right click on 
>    the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."

Can anyone help me? What is problem? Thanks in advance. My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets             and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/dispatcherServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: You should add the error messages to your question.

Answer (score 6):

Try using this URL for the schema definition:

```
http://oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd
```

As mentioned above by @Renardo, the following URL...

```
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app.xsd
```

...redirects to an HTML page that causes an error within Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem although my schemaLocation points to web-app_3_0.xml. With 2_4 the problem did not appear. Now I have found that, used as an http address,

```
java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd
```

is redirected to

```
www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd
```

which is a valid XSD file. However, the same URL with "3_0" instead of "2_4" is redirected to *…/technetwork/java/index.html*, which is an HTML file and contains exactly the texts Eclipse complains of.

I am at a loss as to whether

- Oracle should provide an XSD under that URL, or
- Eclipse should try to get that XSD from elsewhere, or
- I should change my namespace declaration.

My Eclipse errors went away when I changed the namespace from "…/xml/ns/**j2ee**" to "…/xml/ns/**javaee**" and used a URL from Oracle's website that points to a correct XSD. Sorry I cannot post the URL, my low reputation does not allow it.

Comment: "my low reputation does not allow it." lol

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

It looks like the problem was with the Java EE  JARs that ship with MyEclipse… i would never encourage you to copy around plugins from one release to another (just for future reference, it could lead to squirrely problems).
so try above one

Comment: must add the version property

Answer (score 1):

Every time that I get this error I do this

Project -> Properties -> Project Facets
In the right panel looking for Dynamic Web Module and get this version.

For example in my project I'm using **Dynamic Web Module** **3.1**

With this I need to use http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
</weblogic-web-app>
```